# iText7: How to verify signature in detached PKCS7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, pkcs#7

I am writing a service that receives PKCS7 data (extracted from signed PDF documents) and needs to verify it.

I am using iText7 PdfPKCS7 for that, but the signature verification always fails. I can read all other information from the PKCS7 (certificates, timestamps etc., I have verified that also with OpenSSL). Only the signature appears as invalid.

Here's the test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException,
    NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PKCS7Test.class.getName());

    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    String path ="/tmp/signed.pdf";

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
    SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdf);
    List<String> names = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
    String outerRevisionName = names.get(names.size()-1);

    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7In = signatureUtil.verifySignature(outerRevisionName);

    boolean isValidSignature = pkcs7In.verify();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "pkcs7In signature is " + ((isValidSignature)?"":"not ") + "valid");

    // get hash of original document       
    Field digestAttrField = PdfPKCS7.class.getDeclaredField("digestAttr");
    digestAttrField.setAccessible(true);
    byte[] originalDigest = (byte[]) digestAttrField.get(pkcs7In);

    // get pkcs7 structure of original signature                
    PdfDictionary dict = signatureUtil.getSignatureDictionary(outerRevisionName);        
    PdfString contents = dict.getAsString(PdfName.Contents);
    byte [] originalBytes = contents.getValueBytes();
    String originalPkcs7 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalBytes);

    // now reverse process and import PKCS7 data back into object
    byte[] pkcs7Bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(originalPkcs7);
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7Out = new PdfPKCS7(pkcs7Bytes, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, provider.getName());

    isValidSignature = pkcs7Out.verify();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "pkcs7Out signature is " + ((isValidSignature)?"":"not ") + "valid");

    // get hash of original document from imported signature     
    digestAttrField = PdfPKCS7.class.getDeclaredField("digestAttr");
    digestAttrField.setAccessible(true);
    byte [] importedDigest = (byte[]) digestAttrField.get(pkcs7Out);

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Hash values are " + ((Arrays.areEqual(originalDigest, importedDigest))?"":"not ") + "equal");
```

The output is invariably:

```
pkcs7In signature is valid
pkcs7Out signature is not valid
Hash values are equal
```

I suppose I'm doing something wrong with the import, but just can't find out what...

Btw. `/tmp/signed.pdf` validates OK (signature and content) in other PDF tools (Adobe DC, PdfOnline etc.)

Edit:
I tried to verify the signature with BouncyCastle, which fails too ...

```
    CMSSignedData signature = new CMSSignedData(pkcs7Bytes);        

    Store                   certStore = signature.getCertificates();
    SignerInformationStore  signers = signature.getSignerInfos();
    Collection              c = signers.getSigners();
    Iterator                it = c.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        SignerInformation   signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
        Collection          certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID());

        Iterator              certIt = certCollection.iterator();
        X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();

       try {
            signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Failed to verify with: " + cert.getSubject().toString() + ": " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            byte [] contentDigest = signer.getContentDigest();
            bi = new BigInteger(1, contentDigest);
            String hash = String.format("%0" + (contentDigest.length << 1) + "x", bi);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Bouncycastle Hash from pkcs7Out is {0}", hash);
        }
    }
```

The result is `Failed to verify with: ... message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value`, and the hash value obviously differs from the real one...

Edit 2:
Workaround by adding separate `verify(byte[] msgDigestBytes)` method to PdfPKCS7:

```
public boolean verify(final byte[] msgDigestBytes) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (verified)
        return verifyResult;
    if (isTsp) {
        TimeStampTokenInfo info = timeStampToken.getTimeStampInfo();
        MessageImprint imprint = info.toASN1Structure().getMessageImprint();
        byte[] md = msgDigestBytes; // was: messageDigest.digest();
        byte[] imphashed = imprint.getHashedMessage();
        verifyResult = Arrays.equals(md, imphashed);
    } else {
        if (sigAttr != null || sigAttrDer != null) {
            // was: final byte[] msgDigestBytes = messageDigest.digest();
            boolean verifyRSAdata = true;
            // Stefan Santesson fixed a bug, keeping the code backward compatible
            boolean encContDigestCompare = false;
            if (rsaData != null) {
                verifyRSAdata = Arrays.equals(msgDigestBytes, rsaData);
                encContDigest.update(rsaData);
                encContDigestCompare = Arrays.equals(encContDigest.digest(), digestAttr);
            }
            boolean absentEncContDigestCompare = Arrays.equals(msgDigestBytes, digestAttr);
            boolean concludingDigestCompare = absentEncContDigestCompare || encContDigestCompare;
            boolean sigVerify = verifySigAttributes(sigAttr) || verifySigAttributes(sigAttrDer);
            verifyResult = concludingDigestCompare && sigVerify && verifyRSAdata;
        } else {
            if (rsaData != null)
                sig.update(msgDigestBytes); // was: sig.update(messageDigest.digest());
            verifyResult = sig.verify(digest);
        }
    }
    verified = true;
    return verifyResult;
}
```

For this to work, I need the originally signed hash of the document from a trusted source, which in my case I have. Does this still verify that the signature made over the hash is correct?

Comment: Concerning your edit: The "usual" BC validation, just like the usual iText validation, is tailored to also check whether the signature really signs the allegedly signed data. As you appear to not want to check that, you'll also have to customize the workflow here a bit.

Comment: Concerning your second edit: That looks correct (assuming you documented all your changes in comments). *"Does this still verify that the signature made over the hash is correct?"* - Yes, as far as `PdfPKCS7` validation goes. As the generic signature container class it obviously won't go into details, e.g. it won't check for PAdES Baseline profiles, it won't check for algorithm suitability, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

```
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7Out = new PdfPKCS7(pkcs7Bytes, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, provider.getName());

isValidSignature = pkcs7Out.verify();
```

you cannot expect a proper validation result of the signature: This `PdfPKCS7` only knows the CMS signature container, the signature **SubFilter**, and the security provider to provide algorithm implementations. Thus, it has no information on the very PDF the signature actually is meant to sign. So that piece of code has no means to validate the signature in question, in particular not whether it properly signs its alleged signed data!

If you want to validate the signature using that `PdfPKCS7` object, you have to finish initializing it so it does have the required information from the PDF.

To see what is required have a look at the `SignatureUtil` method `verifySignature`:

```
PdfPKCS7 pk = null;
if (sub.equals(PdfName.Adbe_x509_rsa_sha1)) {
    PdfString cert = signature.getPdfObject().getAsString(PdfName.Cert);
    if (cert == null)
        cert = signature.getPdfObject().getAsArray(PdfName.Cert).getAsString(0);
    pk = new PdfPKCS7(PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(contents.getValue(), null), cert.getValueBytes(), provider);
}
else
    pk = new PdfPKCS7(PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(contents.getValue(), null), sub, provider);
updateByteRange(pk, signature);
PdfString date = signature.getDate();
if (date != null)
    pk.setSignDate(PdfDate.decode(date.toString()));
String signName = signature.getName();
pk.setSignName(signName);
String reason = signature.getReason();
if (reason != null)
    pk.setReason(reason);
String location = signature.getLocation();
if (location != null)
    pk.setLocation(location);
```

Thus, you have to

- update the digest of the signed data like `SignatureUtil.updateByteRange` does; this is the step that informs the `PdfPKCS7` object about the actually signed data to allow actual validation; and
- copy several pieces of information from the signature dictionary to the `PdfPKCS7` object; for validation purposes in particular the signing time may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see how that information would be available when I only get the PKCS7. Especially there's no dictionary to read the signature from `PdfSignature signature = getSignature(name);` On the other hand, both the hash that was signed and the signature are available in the PKCS7, so it should be possible to verify that without knowledge of the PDF structure. Or can this not be done with PdfPKCS7? Maybe I need to use BC directly?

Comment: *"But I don't see how that information would be available when I only get the PKCS7"* - for a proper validation that does not suffice. You actually may need much more, in particular all validation related information also stored in the pdf file...

Comment: *"both the hash that was signed and the signature are available in the PKCS7"* - but you also have to check whether that "hash that was signed" indeed is the hash of the original pdf revision! If you don't verify that, you merely check whether the signature internally is ok but not whether it actually applies to the pdf document revision it allegedly signs! And the full validation is what `PdfPKCS7` verification is designed to check.

Comment: If your service really shall only validate the internal integrity of the CMS container and the check whether it applies to the allegedly signed PDF revision occurs elsewhere, you can simply copy the code of the `PdfPKCS7.verify` method  (and some non-public other methods from that class) and remove the validation of the actual document hash.

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed I "only" need to verify cryptographically that the signature in the PKCS7 matches the hash there. Both should be in the `pkcs7-data` part, afaict. The hash and revision number from the PDF will be checked separately. I have tried to verify the signature with BouncyCastle (see edited question), but that fails too... really lost now :-[

Comment: *'Indeed I "only" need to verify cryptographically that the signature in the PKCS7 matches the hash there. Both should be in the pkcs7-data part, afaict.'* - So you only need to check whether the signature value in the single SignerInfo object in the signature container signs the signed attributes of it? Or are you also expected to check the signer certificate? What about time stamps? What about algorithm assessment? Etc. ...

Comment: I check all of that (certs, timestamps, algos ec) separately based on the data returned by PdfPKCS7. All the required data is available when I load the pkcs7 the way shown above. It's just the signature verification that fails, because the `verify()` method expects to be able to calculate the message digest itself and compare it to the `digestAttr` from the imported pkcs7. I can work around that by patching PdfPKCS7 with an additional `verify()` method that accepts the original digest as a byte[]. See Edit 2 of question.

Comment: *"I can work around that by patching PdfPKCS7 with an additional verify() method that accepts the original digest as a byte[]"* - That'll work ok even if it's a bit burdensome to update iText versions if you have to patch them each time. But *"All the required data is available when I load the pkcs7"* - that may be true if you only want to validate ISO 32000-1 P7 signatures but as soon you wish to validate for non-trivial PAdES profiles (using structures also defined in ISO 32000-2), you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I know :-(. But those would probably not be verified by PdfPKCS7 in iText either. As for the patching: I currently don't see any other way to accomplish what is required here: Verify a detached signature without having the original document (only the hash). I'll go with the "solution" from  Edit 2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"But those would probably not be verified by PdfPKCS7 in iText either."* - Right, not the naked `PdfPKCS7`. But the iText class `LtvVerifier` shows how one can use multiple `PdfPKCS7` and the VRI in the DSS sections for a more complete verification. That code can also serve as inspiration for code checking profiles as all relevant information is retrieved somewhere along the way. *"Thanks for your help!"* - You're welcome!